# how to remove file name and folder name from the url by htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have used code that area give  below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

but by using these code I can only remove only one page name .
can you guys please help me with this.

In other words, I want to change the URL from:

www.xyz.com/blog/post1/post3
   www.xyz.com/blog/post2/post4

To:

```
   www.xyz.com/post3  
   www.xyz.com/post4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(?:.*/)?([^/]+)/?$ /$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

This will redirect `/blog/post1/post3` to `/post3` and `/blog/post2` to `/post2`.